# Верная конвертация из Excel в CSV

Tags: excel, конвертация, csv

При конвертации **Excel** в **csv** он ломает номера телефонов в такой формат(столбец ***billingPhone***)

Исходный **Excel**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После "сохранить как **CSV**":

[image: Поломанные номера]

Как мне верно сохранить/экспортировать дату с **Excel** без поломок?

Answer (score 1):

Это проблема отображения, а не конвертации. Исчезла информация о формате ячеек и Excel ошибочно считает данные числами. Если CSV вам нужен только для импорта (напр. в БД), то просто перестаньте волноваться.